# Split each two-word string in a list, compare if same and count using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

Is it possible to split each string (containing 2 words) in a list, then compare if both words are the same and count that occurrences using Linq? For example:

Let's say I have a list containing

```
list[0] = "bla bla";
list[1] = "bla heh";
list[2] = "heh heh";
```

The output of count should be 2 in this case.

my attempt so far:

```
var count = lst.Count(c => c.Split(.......)....
```

can't get past this.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: yes possible but have you tried anything?

Comment: I'm stuck, because I don't know how to get that 2 strings, eg. var count = lst.Count(c => c.Split(.......).....; Can't get past this.

Comment: @angrysomoan I've done it already, but in the future please include your attempt in the post instead of doing it in comments.

Comment: Will do! Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can utilise the `Select` clause then the `Count` like so:

```
 int count = myList.Select(s => s.Split(' '))
                   .Count(a => a[0] == a[1]);
```

or you can use `Count` only like this:

```
 int count = myList.Count(s => s.Substring(0, s.IndexOf(' ')) == 
                                 s.Substring(s.IndexOf(' ') + 1));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
list.Select(c => c.Split(' ')).Count(y => y.Length >= 2 && y[0] == y[1]);
```

Comment: Oops, didn't  know some else answered

Comment: But yours may be better because it doesn't throw exceptions (depending on what the Op wanted to happen when there aren't two words). :)

Answer (score 2):

With the new `Span<T>` value type (see [this article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt814808.aspx)) from nuget package 'System.Memory' you can do this without any unnecessary allocations:

```
        int count = input.Count(x => 
        {
           int index = x.IndexOf(' ');
           if (index < 1 || index == x.Length - 1) return false;
           var span = x.AsSpan();
           return span.Slice(start:0, length:index)           // no allocation
               .SequenceEqual(
                   span.Slice(start: index + 1));             // no allocation
        });
```

Comment: I like this attempt and the fact it saves memory :)

Answer (score 1):

Same as the others, but if you would have 3 or more words it would check them against eachother and only count the arrays that have the same words everywhere.

```
var result = test.Select(x => x.Split(' ')).Count(x => x.All(y => x[0] == y));
```